# C# mails not being sent sometimes, but no error is thrown

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

This is my code :

```
public static void SendMail(string to, string subject, string body, string mailTitle)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.Subject =  subject;
    mail.From = new MailAddress("***", mailTitle);
    mail.To.Add(to);
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;          

    SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient("leavingstone.net", 25);
    c.EnableSsl = false;
    c.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "***");

    c.Send(mail);
}
```

Sometimes mails are sent, other times not - but no error is thrown.

Is it possible to fix the problem from code, or is it host fail?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't send the e-mail? Are you sure the e-mail address you are trying to send it to actually exists?

Comment: first of all, you should dispose all  your disposables. secondly do you mean the mail is not received? if you have a mailbox attached to your sender address you might get bounce messages

Comment: have you taken a look at the log on the smtp server?

Comment: Yeah mail not recieved, it's not also in the spam folder.

Comment: But sometimes it works

Comment: Probably being rate limited by your smtp server then. Are you flooding messages? (Sending multiple messages in a short space of time?)

Comment: Then don't do that. Your smtp server will be trying to stop people sending spam mail, which to them it looks like you're doing.

Comment: But i 've application and if some condition happens  spefic mails should has to be sent to some people.

Comment: So i have to contact to my server administrator?

Comment: Yes. If it's only a few emails in a short space of time they may permit it (and you may just need a second or two delay between messages), but there will be an hourly/daily threshold somewhere and you may be at risk of crossing it. They're the best people to explain the situation to and ask for advice.

Comment: According to the documentation, the `SmtpClient.Send()` should throw an exception if a mail cannot be sent to some recipients. It doesn't say so explicitly but as I read the documentation, the intent is that the absence of an exception indicates success. The design decision to make `Send()` a void function points in that direction, too. So I would assume that on your sending side everything went ok. The problem is then on the server or the recipients side. Server: google "smtp server silently discarding mail". Recipient side: All kinds of reasons.

Comment: And  also remember that mails bounce only after a certain period of time as undeliverable, probably days. So the server accepted your mail alright, but it cannot deliver it, and you'll only learn about it next monday.

Answer (score 0):

Try my SMTP code, works perfect for me !

```
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "mail.domain.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean("false");
            NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = "no-reply@domain.com";
            NetworkCred.Password = "**************";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt16(25);
            smtp.Send(mm);
```

Comment: Any particular reason for Convert.ToBoolean("false") instead of simply assigning a boolean value like smtp.EnableSsl = false;?

Comment: It's a same thing.
SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient("leavingstone.net", 25);
Here add mail server domain, something like "mail.leavingstone.net" ?

Comment: Well of course it returns bool otherwise it wouldn't compile but it's just weird. Anyway, I  got my answer.

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy The conversion is of course nonsense here but may come because the code originally used a text configuration file so that the original argument was a string variable extracted from the file; for this example it was replaced by a constant.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Great point reading the value from config. Yeah, that must be it. Thank you.